# Nco failed to initialize UDUnits2 library

Tags: python, netcdf, nco

I have no experience in Nco,but when i try to concatenate files using (ncrcat),I get the following error,I tried nco 4.2.0, 4.6.3,4.7.5,4.9.5 with no change,4.2 worked however time dimension had the same values for all time intervals,.I'm working on windows 10 i installed conda-nco but still can't find any documentation any help or guide would be deeply appreciated,I say again complete beginner.Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

UDUnits2 (specifically, the function `ut_read_xml()`) uses the environment variable `UDUNITS2_XML_PATH`, if any, to find its all-important XML database named `udunits2.xml` by default.
If `UDUNITS2_XML_PATH` is undefined, UDUnits2 looks in the fall-back default initial location that was hardcoded when the UDUnits2 library was built.
This location varies depending upon your operating system and UDUnits2 compilation settings.
If UDUnits2 is correctly linked yet cannot find the XML database in either of these locations,
then NCO will report that the UDUnits2 library has failed to initialize.
To fix this, export the location of the UDUnits2 XML database file `udunits2.xml` to the shell:

```
   export UDUNITS2_XML_PATH='/opt/local/share/udunits/udunits2.xml'
```

One can then invoke (without recompilation) NCO again, and UDUNITS2 should work.